# Как поменять все значения в таблице с условием что одно поле не равно null

Tags: mysql

есть такая таблица

```
1   id          
2   id_gods     
3   id_post     
4   id_cat  
5   id_page     
6   path    
7   name    
8   forHome
```

мне надо изменить значение `forHome` если значение `id_gods` не равно `null`
пишу так

```
UPDATE `abh_image` `forHome`=1 WHERE `id_gods` IS NOT NULL
```

получаю ошибку

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=1 WHERE `id_gods` = IS NOT NULL' at

Понимаю что делаю, что то не то но как правильно не нашел. Подскажите как привильно ?

Comment: слово `SET` потеряли при оформлении вопроса или вообще?)
`UPDATE abh_image SET forHome=1 WHERE id_gods IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @Moonvvell спасибо

Comment: @Sergalas, неужели так сложно проверить синтаксис mysql запроса? Куча источников, а Вы идете задавать вопрос, который уже сотнями сдублирован.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Неправильный синтаксис UPDATE: SET пропустили.

Правильный:

```
UPDATE `abh_image` SET `forHome`=1 WHERE `id_gods` IS NOT NULL
```