# Как скопировать данные из одной ячейки в другую?

Tags: mysql

Но вот только с одним условием если ячейка в которую копируют равна null.
И так есть таблица `goods` в кторой есть столбцы `create_at` и `update_at` .Мне надо скопировать данные из c`reate_at`  в `update_at`, но только если `update_at` равен `null`

Comment: Хм. судя по предыдущим вопросам https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/578050/ вы знаете про существование update и даже условие на not null писали. Так вот, если условие изменить на противоположное (`is null`) и в set вместо константы 1 указать название другого поля то такой update сработает

Comment: @Mike про update я знаю и понимаю что надо делать что то вроде такого `UPDATE goods SET update_at = create_at` но я не понимаю как поставить условие если update_at is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE goods SET update_at = goods.create_at WHERE update_at IS NULL;
```

Comment: А не на оборот ? мне надо менять update_at ?

Comment: @Sergalas В тексте вопроса вы пишите "_если update_at равен null_". В запросе "`WHERE update_at IS NULL`". По моему это практически дословный перевод условия которое вы хотели ...

Comment: @Sergalas Вообще технология подготовки таких запросов простая: сначала пишите select который выберет именно те записи, которые надо менять. Убеждаетесь, что он дал именно то что требуется. После чего меняете select на update

Comment: @Mike  Спасибо за совет чего то не додумался